# java selenium webdriver Select from dropdown menu select by value ignore case sensitivity

Tags: java, select, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver, html-select

I have a problem to select from dropdown menu by using SelectByValue ignoring case sensitivity.

For example: 
    
        
        Japan
        Albania

As it is seen value is Japan. However, the value which I have can be "japan" or "Japan".

I can able to select by using. However, it takes considerable amount of time if the list is huge.

```
// get dropdown elements
Select dropdown = new Select(findElementHelper(by));
// get elements based on options from dropdown menu
List<WebElement> myElements = dropdown.getOptions(); //because of  listing takes time
// test until value of element and given value is equal
String tempValue = value.trim();
for (WebElement option : myElements) {
    if (tempValue.equalsIgnoreCase(option.getAttribute("value").trim())) {
        // tryClick(option,value) did not work on ie
        /*if (!tryClick(option,value)){
            System.out.println(value + " is not selected");
           return false;
       } option.click(); //worked one
        break;
    }
}
```

I have tried Select class with proper input and it works much faster than my code. Is there any way to ignore case sensitivity in selectByValue.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Selenium implementation of selectByValue() searches for the given value using xpath instead of looping through all of the options. You should be able to change the xpath search to be change everything to lowercase instead. If you know there will only be one option with the given value then you can simplify this further by removing the List and for loop.

```
WebElement dropdownElement = findElementHelper(by);

String tempValue = value.trim().toLowerCase();

List<WebElement> matchingValues = dropdownElement.findElements(By.xpath(
        ".//option[lower-case(@value) = '" + tempValue + "']"));    

for(WebElement matchingValue : matchingValues)
{
     /* Do what you want with the options         
     if (!option.isSelected()) {
         option.click();
     } */
}
```

I don't work with Selenium in Java so I'm not able to test this but it should be pretty close. Let me know if this is faster.

Comment: dropdown is the returned Select object, therefore,    dropdown.findElements(By.xpath(
        ".//option[lower-case(@value) = " + tempValue + "]")); will not work. If dropdown was WebDriver, it may work for unique values. However, the website has a lots of same value.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. You just need to get the regular element instead of the select element. I will edit the example.

Comment: It will not work for my case because there are same values for different dropdown menus

Comment: @cshsnou `WebElement dropdownElement = findElementHelper(by);` should find the unique dropdown. If you noticed, matchingValues is now taken from `dropdownElement.findElements()` so the scope is limited to that.

Comment: Sorry i have recently realized you have updated the coding. I have tried lower-case but it was not existed in java xpath. Therefore, i have used:  WebElement option = dropdown.findElement(By.xpath("//option[translate(@value, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='"+tempValue.toLowerCase()+"']")); But it  may cause problem if the value has space or other characters